# Basic powershell, wsus managing

Tags: windows, powershell

have few basic question for you, how to list servers belongs to group in wsus? Is there any possibility? I cannot find it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a free script writing service. Your own research and code attempts are expected. Edit the question to include your code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 0):

From the WSUS server assuming it has the UpdateServices module installed:

```
Import-Module UpdateServices

Get-WsusComputer -ComputerTargetGroups "GroupName"
```